# Removing absolute filepath name from rollup dist file

Tags: javascript, rollupjs

When I run rollup to output my React JSX files, including in the index.es.js and index.js are the following:

```
var _jsxFileName = '/Users/<name>/<path>/<to>/component-lib/src/button/Button.js',
```

For my Button component. This creates merge conflicts when different developers do the rollup builds.

Is there an easy way to strip this path from the file?
Ideally it would just be:

```
var _jsxFileName = '/component-lib/src/button/Button.js',
```

This is my current rollup config:

```
import babel from 'rollup-plugin-babel'
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs'
import external from 'rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external'
import postcss from 'rollup-plugin-postcss'
import resolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve'
import url from 'rollup-plugin-url'
import svgr from '@svgr/rollup'

import pkg from './package.json'

const path = require("path");

process.env.NODE_ENV = 'development';

// console.log('resolve', resolve().options);
// console.log('url', url({
//     sourceDir: path.join(__dirname, "src"),
//     fileName: "[hash][name][extname]",
//     publicPath: "/"
// }));
export default {
  input: 'src/index.js',
  output: [
    {
      file: pkg.main,
      format: 'cjs',
      sourcemap: true,
      entryFileNames:"entry-[name].js"
    },
    {
      file: pkg.module,
      format: 'es',
      sourcemap: true,
      entryFileNames:"entry-[name].js"
    }
  ],
  plugins: [
    external(),
    postcss({
      modules: true
    }),
    url({
      // sourceDir: path.join(__dirname, "src"),
      // fileName: "[hash][name][extname]",
      // publicPath: "/"
    }),
    svgr(),
    babel({
      exclude: 'node_modules/**',
      plugins: [ 'external-helpers' ]
    }),
    resolve(),
    commonjs()
  ]
}
```